# Listing a company as the copyright holder of an R package

Tags: r, package, cran

What's the best way to give copyright to a company for an R package? [Hadley](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html) points to some options, but I'm still uncertain of the best practice. In the DESCRIPTION, I would prefer to write something like

```
Authors@R: c(
    person(given = c("First", "Middle"), family = "Family", email = "me@company.com", role = c("aut, cre")),
    person(given = "Company", role = "cph"))
```

but this is awkward because corporations are not people. Another option:

```
Authors@R: person(given = c("First", "Middle"), family = "Family", email = "me@company.com", role = c("aut, cre"))
License: GPL (>=3) + file LICENSE
```

where `LICENSE` contains

```
Copyright <My Company>. All rights reserved.
```

But can I really do that with GPL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Briefly:

- Copyright and License are two different and separate concepts. The DESCRIPTION file allows for both, and the [official manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) has things to say about both.
- Many *existing* CRAN packages deal with that.  For the use of assigned copyright, packages by RStudio employees can sometimes serve as examples.  See [for example this line from dplyr](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/DESCRIPTION#L10).
- Legal stuff is hard. And boring. Don't take StackOverflow answers as binding either.

Comment: Thanks, Dirk! Now that I am aware of some precedent, I can plan and confirm with my colleagues.